# How to connect Wix Answers to my SSO server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, single-sign-on

I made a makeshift 'sso server' which I want to connect to Wix Answers. Wix is a CMS. Wix Answers is a help center where you can customer FAQs, have customers receive support videos, and the customer can enter tickets. Wix answers are what Wix uses for Wix's help pages and they make the same app available to users for the same purpose.

My 'sso server' is an AWS API Gateway pointing to a Lambda function. Pretty straight forward. You call the public endpoint and it runs this lambda:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var crypto = require('crypto'); //npm install crypto --save
var base64url = require('base64url'); //npm install base64url --save

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var KEY_ID = '1234567'; //note it's a uuid
var SECRET = '1234567xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

exports.handler = async (event) => {

  //this assumes there is a login or some UI that will receive the needed redirect url
    app.get('/login-form', function (request, response) {
    var url = require('url');
    var urlParts = url.parse(request.url, true);
    var query = urlParts.query;
    var answersRedirectUrl = query.redirectUrl;

    //of course, in a real system the data will come from your own user system
    var dummyUserData = {
        id: 'your-user-id',
        email: 'user@email.com',
        firstName: 'Bob2',
        lastName: 'Bobson',
        profileImage: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-90CAdWk27I/maxresdefault.jpg',
        timestamp: Date.now()
    };

    var token = encryptUserData(JSON.stringify(dummyUserData), SECRET);
    response.redirect(answersRedirectUrl + '&token=' + token + '&key=' + KEY_ID);
    });

};

function encryptUserData(data, key) {
  var iv = new Buffer('');
  var bytes = new Buffer(key, 'utf-8');
  var hashedKey = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(bytes).digest().slice(0, 16);

  var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ecb', hashedKey, iv);
  var crypted = cipher.update(data, 'UTF-8', 'hex');
  crypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return base64url(new Buffer(crypted, 'hex'));
}
```

This code is a lambda modified version of the code Wix Answers sample js code from, here.
https://help.wixanswers.com/en/article/setting-up-single-sign-on-sso-for-your-users

There are dependencies, and I have loaded them all into a lambda, so its not a dependency issue.

Wix Answers is an easy setup, you give them a url for login and logout. you generate a key inside of Wix answers dashboard, and I have added that key to my lambda below (the ones below are masked obviously). I've added my endpoint to the field in wix answers.

I'm getting a `null` response and was able to get an object with object.message = `"missing auth token"`

Focusing on the JS and the lambda, is there anything that I am leaving out that would make this not work. Again not a lot of experience with express and these dependencies, or with SSO.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wix Has some good tools but lacks documentation sometimes. Here is how I solved this problem:

tutorial https://help.wixanswers.com/en/article/setting-up-single-sign-on-sso-for-your-users

their JS code from https://gist.github.com/GabiGrin/0c92ecbb071e02e2d91c8d689517acd7#file-answers-sso-example-js

What I did

```
//encrypt.js
var crypto = require('crypto'); //built in to node
var base64url = require('base64url'); //requires install 'npm install base64url'
var KEY_ID = 'abcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; //from Wix Answers
var SECRET = 'fakefakefakefakefakefake'; //from Wix Answers

let user = {
    id: '123456',
    email: 'email@domain.com',
    firstName: 'Homer',
    lastName: 'Simpson',
    profileImage: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-90CAdWk27I/maxresdefault.jpg',
    timestamp: Date.now()
};

function encryptUserData(data, key) {
    var iv = new Buffer('');
    var bytes = new Buffer(key, 'utf-8');
    var hashedKey = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(bytes).digest().slice(0, 16);

    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ecb', hashedKey, iv);
    var crypted = cipher.update(data, 'UTF-8', 'hex');
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return base64url(new Buffer(crypted, 'hex'));
}

var token = encryptUserData(JSON.stringify(user), SECRET);
console.log(`https://mysite.wixanswers.com/api/v1/accounts/callback/sso?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.wixanswers.com%2Fen&token=${token}&key=${KEY_ID}`);
```

Since my project is a concept, I have not integrated with a real identity server, as you can see i skip the authentication and go right to authorization (for my hard coded user: Homer Simpson). To mkae it work i'd need to add authentication and pass a dynamic user object to an export function in the module.

for the sake of the concept tho:

from the shell 'node encrypt.js'
returns a redirect URL in the console - when followed, successfully signs you into the Wix Answers platform with the proper user object.